Double if statement in excel
I'm not expert in excel programming and I want to write this formula in excel:

If A10 is "Hello" and H10 is blank, it returns D7x5.5, else it should return D8x5.5
If A10 is "Hello" and H10 is not blank, it returns D7xH10, else it should return D8xH10

thanks for support.

You could try using the following formula:
=IFS(
    AND(
        A10 = "Hello" ,H10 = ""
    ) ,D7 * 5.5,
    AND(
        A10 <> "Hello" ,H10 = ""
    ) ,D8 * 5.5,
    AND(
        A10 = "Hello" ,H10 <> ""
    ) ,D7 * H10,1,D8 * H10
)


The above formula takes into account about all the conditions outlined in the OP:
• If A10 is "Hello" and H10 is blank, it returns D7x5.5, else it should return D8x5.5
• If A10 is "Hello" and H10 is not blank, it returns D7xH10, else it should return D8xH10

For Older Versions:
=IF(
    AND(
        A10 = "Hello" ,H10 = ""
    ) ,D7 * 5.5,
    IF(
        AND(
            A10 <> "Hello" ,H10 = ""
        ) ,D8 * 5.5,
        IF(
            AND(
                A10 = "Hello" ,H10 <> ""
            ) ,D7 * H10,D8 * H10
        )
    )
)


As per comments of OP, they are using Excel in Italian Version, therefore here is the version alternative:
=SE(E(A10="Hello";H10="");D7*5,5;SE(E(A10<>"Hello";H10="");D8*5,5;SE(E(A10="Hello";H10<>"");D7*H10;D8*H10)))



replacing the , with ; and 5.5 with 5,5 it accepted the formula but it gives #name?

@Inuyasha84 what is your excel version?

@Inuyasha84 then use the following: =IF(AND(A10="Hello",H10=""),D7*5.5,IF(AND(A10<>"Hello",H10=""),D8*5.5,IF(AND(A10="Hello",H10<>""),D7*H10,D8*H10)))

the version is  2308 Build 16.0.16731.20542

I tried and it says #name?

@Inuyasha84 are you using Excel in English version

no it is in italian

@Inuyasha84 try : =SE(E(A10="Hello";H10="");D7*5,5;SE(E(A10<>"Hello";H10="");D8*5,5;SE(E(A10="Hello";H10<>"");D7*H10;D8*H10)))

damn!I'm so stupid!you're right!I was still thinking in C programming using the if statement. Thanks for support!
